# 'PlanetarySystem.Type' does not have a member named 'Planets'

Tags: swift, class, types, member

This line is in the main area, and I'm pretty sure it's the source of the issue:

```
let planetarySystem = PlanetarySystem(name: "Solar System",planets: [Planet]()) //Name of the solar system
```

And in a different document for my "Planets" class, the code follows:

```
import Foundation

class Planet {

    let name: String
    let description: String

    init(name: String, description: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.description = description
    }
    init() {
        let mercury = Planet(name: "Mercury", description: "A very hot planet, closest to the sun.")
        let venus = Planet(name: "Veuns", description: "A dangerous planet of completely toxic air.")
        let earth = Planet(name: "Earth", description: "Your home. Looks familiar, right?")
        let mars = Planet(name: "Mars", description: "A red planet. Recently water was found on it.")
        let jupiter = Planet(name: "Jupiter", description: "Largest planet in the Solar System.")
        let saturn = Planet(name: "Saturn", description: "Beautiful rings surround this gas planet.")
        let uranus = Planet(name: "Uranus", description: "This is a planet that rotates on its side.")
        let neptune = Planet(name: "Neptune", description: "Little is known about this gas giant.")

        PlanetarySystem.planets.append(mercury)
        PlanetarySystem.planets.append(venus)
        PlanetarySystem.planets.append(earth)
        PlanetarySystem.planets.append(mars)
        PlanetarySystem.planets.append(jupiter)
        PlanetarySystem.planets.append(saturn)
        PlanetarySystem.planets.append(uranus)
        PlanetarySystem.planets.append(neptune)
    }
}
```

According to anyone who helps, my program is "right". Yet the issue is never resolved. If you need to see all sections of my program in order to help, there is a zip file with all components (Xcode file) [at this Google Drive URL](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxiEnz51C3vHdlBBMERTeGpVc0E/view?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 1):

#### Direct answer to your question

Error comes from `PlanetarySystem.planets.append(mercury)`.

You need to create an instance of a `PlanetarySystem` object before accessing its `planets` property.

#### 1st answer (literal)

- The `PlanetarySystem` class (that you should have shown in your question) has an array of planets in its initializer, use it instead of using `append` many times.
- Your generic `init()` wants to append all these planets to an array, but where would be this array? In my example I've make it a property of the Planet class. But it looks like you actually would use it elsewhere.
- Because `self.name` and `self.description` are not Optionals, you have to initialize them in the generic `init()` too. Or go the other way like in my example and make them Optionals.

---

```
class Planet {

    var name: String?
    var description: String?
    var fromSystem: PlanetarySystem?

    init(name: String, description: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.description = description
    }
    init() {
        let mercury = Planet(name: "Mercury", description: "A very hot planet, closest to the sun.")
        let venus = Planet(name: "Veuns", description: "A dangerous planet of completely toxic air.")
        let earth = Planet(name: "Earth", description: "Your home. Looks familiar, right?")
        let mars = Planet(name: "Mars", description: "A red planet. Recently water was found on it.")
        let jupiter = Planet(name: "Jupiter", description: "Largest planet in the Solar System.")
        let saturn = Planet(name: "Saturn", description: "Beautiful rings surround this gas planet.")
        let uranus = Planet(name: "Uranus", description: "This is a planet that rotates on its side.")
        let neptune = Planet(name: "Neptune", description: "Little is known about this gas giant.")

        self.fromSystem = PlanetarySystem(name: "Solar System", planets: [mercury, venus, earth, mars, jupiter, saturn, uranus, neptune])

    }
}
```

So, this version works, but there's some logic problems in my opinion.

---

#### 2nd answer (my interpretation)

It would be better to create a PlanetarySystem object from elsewhere than inside the generic init of a Planet object.

For example:

```
class Planet {
    var name: String
    var description: String
    init(name: String, description: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.description = description
    }
}

class PlanetarySystem {
    let name: String
    let planets: [Planet]
    init(name: String, planets: [Planet]) {
        self.name = name
        self.planets = planets
    }

}

let mercury = Planet(name: "Mercury", description: "A very hot planet, closest to the sun.")
let venus = Planet(name: "Veuns", description: "A dangerous planet of completely toxic air.")
let earth = Planet(name: "Earth", description: "Your home. Looks familiar, right?")
let mars = Planet(name: "Mars", description: "A red planet. Recently water was found on it.")
let jupiter = Planet(name: "Jupiter", description: "Largest planet in the Solar System.")
let saturn = Planet(name: "Saturn", description: "Beautiful rings surround this gas planet.")
let uranus = Planet(name: "Uranus", description: "This is a planet that rotates on its side.")
let neptune = Planet(name: "Neptune", description: "Little is known about this gas giant.")

let system = PlanetarySystem(name: "Solar system", planets: [mercury, venus, earth, mars, jupiter, saturn, uranus, neptune])
```

*I actually believe this version is what you intended from the beginning, but I also wanted to answer your question literally, just in case... so that's what I've done in the first part of this answer.*